# Docker Stack/Compose Redis Instance Not Persisting Data

Tags: docker, redis

I'm trying to use Redis as a cache in my Sails.js application, but am having a hard time getting the volumes to work correctly and to get the Redis instance to persist the data automatically.

Here's (the relevant part of) my stack.yml file:

```
redis:
  image: 'redis:latest'
  command: redis-server --appendonly yes
  command: ['redis-server', '--requirepass', 'mypasswordgoeshere']
  volumes:
    - ./redis-data:/data
  deploy:
    replicas: 1
```

I have a Sails.js service and an Angular app service as well, but didn't show them as they aren't really needed here.

The above doesn't work exactly as expected out of the box. I expected Docker to create the `./redis-data` folder for me automatically if not present, but it doesn't. So I had to create the folder and make sure the permissions were set correctly. Then I expected the Redis container to persist its data to an `appendonly.aof` file and have that automatically be saved periodically. That's what happens on my local machine when I tried this.

However, on the server, it doesn't save the `appendonly.aof` file for me, and thus the data I want to persist doesn't get saved so that it's there when the stack is restarted.

The weirdest part of this is that I created a volume for the Sails.js app to get to the log files, and I didn't need to create the folder for the application; it just created it and everything worked as expected on its own. Am I missing something obvious here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### EDIT

Also, if I go in to the container (`docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash`, there's nothing in that `/data` folder that it drops you in. Which explains why there's nothing there on the host machine either.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using Redis Stack, what resolved my problem was adding the following

```
environment:
    REDIS_ARGS: --save 20 1
```

I assume any values for the parameters, or using the AOF mode, would also work, but I have not verified this.

I initially tried specifying this as

```
command: redis-server --save 20 1
```

which was based on [this](https://geshan.com.np/blog/2022/01/redis-docker/) tutorial. However, this resulted in a `ConnectionError("Connection is not ready")` ([source](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/blob/bea72995fd39b01e2f0a1682b16b6c7690933f36/redis/connection.py#L1399)) when running `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Thank you! I can't find any reference to this in the docs about persisting the container, but adding that to my compose file now persists the redis graph and that data survives a container deletion, and is present when I compose up again. :-)

Comment: Also works with named docker volumes, as you would expect.

Comment: And `REDIS_ARGS: --appendonly yes` also works

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, declaring REDIS_ARGS env variables did not work for me. What worked was specifying `--dir` folder for redis-server and adding persistence method directly in the redis-server commmand. I am using both AOF & RDB methods for persistence. The full command is:
`redis-server --dir /data --requirepass $REDIS_PASSWORD --save 60 1 --appendonly yes`.

Also, if you need to load modules, use the command
`redis-server --dir /data --requirepass $REDIS_PASSWORD --save 60 1 --appendonly yes --loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisearch.so --loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/rejson.so`

Here is the docker compose version(3)

```yaml
    services:
      localredis:
        image: redis/redis-stack-server:latest
        container_name: rediscontainer
        # environment:
        #   REDIS_ARGS: --save 60 1 --appendonly yes
        command: redis-server --dir /data --requirepass $REDIS_PASSWORD --save 60 1 --appendonly yes
        ports:
          - 6379:6379
        volumes:
          - redis_data:/data
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "-h", "localhost", "-p", "6379", "ping"]
          interval: 2s
          timeout: 1m30s
          retries: 5
          start_period: 5s
        restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      redis_data:
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, I used the following definition for the Redis service:

```
redis:
    image: 'redis:latest'
    environment:
        - REDIS_PASS=mypassword
        - REDIS_APPENDONLY=yes
        - REDIS_APPENDFSYNC=always
    volumes:
        - ./redis-data:/data
    deploy:
        replicas: 1
```

Using the `environment` variables or settings seemed to work as expected.

I got this idea from [this mini tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/getting-started/deploy-app/11_service_stacks/) in the Docker docs. I'm not exactly sure why this worked, as the documentation on Docker Hub for the redis image didn't specify any of those environment variables, and actually said to use to the steps mentioned in the original question, but regardless of that this solution do work.